# Remove just one GET parameter from url and rewrite another if a certain GET param isn't present - htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to set some very specific conditions on a url rewrite but I'm struggling.

Let's say I have a url like `http://www.example.com/?product=test&retailer=test&site=test`

In this instance (where `product` parameter is present) I just want to remove `&site=test` but leave the rest of the url untouched.

If `product` parameter isn't present, e.g. `http://www.example.com/?retailer=test&site=test`

I still want to remove `&site=test` and change `?retailer=test` to `/retailer/test` so the full url would be `http://www.example.com/retailer/test`.  I also only want this to happen on the root domain. Really struggling even just to remove `site` parameter...

I tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)sitechange=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ ? [L,R=301]
```

but this removes all parameters in all instances

Also tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  (.*)?&?site=[^&]+&?(.*)?  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)
RewriteRule .*  %3?%1%2? [R=301,L]
```

but this does nothing. Finding it really hard to get my head around these rewrite rules. If anyone could help it would me much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your parameters are sometimes `product` and always `retailer` and `site` (in that order), your rules should look like this

```
# first condition
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^product=([^&\s]+)&retailer=([^&\s]+)&site=test$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /?product=%1&retailer=%2 [R=301,L]

# second condition
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^retailer=([^&\s]+)&site=test$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /retailer/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks I will give this a but yeah by root domain I mean only on the www.example.com/

Comment: @Neil I've added the needed condition in both rules to match only `www` domain

Comment: Thanks so much this worked. I know its another question really but you would happen to know how I could change "+" to "-" in the argument on this bit would you?

`RewriteRule ^$ /retailer/%1? [R=301,L]`

Comment: You mean replacing a `+` by a `-` in `retailer` parameter ? Assuming you have for instance `?retailer=one+thing` ?

Comment: yes that correct, being doing some looking into it but struggling again. Need to swat up on this rewrite stuff. So would be /retailer/one-thing

Comment: I'd suggest you to post another question, starting from this question, as it would change several things from this answer

Comment: no worries, done this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133021/htaccess-replace-characters-in-query-parameter

Answer (score 1):

Try with below rules I am assuming index.php as handler and assuming other constraints are handled by you.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^product=([^/]+)&retailer=([^/]+)&site=([^/]+)$
RewriteRule ^ index.php?product=%1&retailer=%2 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^retailer=([^/]+)&site=([^/]+)
RewriteRule ^ /retailer/%1? [R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. The second rule works well but the first one does not work unfortunately :(