# htaccess replace characters in query parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a url like http://www.example.com/?product=test&retailer=test&site=test

In this instance (where product parameter is present) I remove &site=test but leave the rest of the url untouched.

If product parameter isn't present, e.g. http://www.example.com/?retailer=test&site=test

I remove &site=test and change ?retailer=test to /retailer/test so the full url would be http://www.example.com/retailer/test. I also only make this happen on the root domain.

I do this using these rules

```
# first condition
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^product=([^&\s]+)&retailer=([^&\s]+)&site=test$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /?product=%1&retailer=%2 [R=301,L]

# second condition
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^retailer=([^&\s]+)&site=test$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /retailer/%1? [R=301,L]
```

on the second rule when the url is rewritten to /reatiler/test there is the possibility for this to be /retailer/test+test in this instance I need to change it to /retailer/test-test could also be /retailer/test+test+test which would need to be /retailer/test-test-test

help on this would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `N` flag (more info [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_n)):

```
RewriteRule ^retailer/(.*)\+(.*)$ /retailer/$1-$2 [N,R=301]
```

Note that this is actually equivalent, since a redirect is involved here:

```
RewriteRule ^retailer/(.*)\+(.*)$ /retailer/$1-$2 [R=301,L]
```

So finally your htaccess should look like this

```
# first condition
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^product=([^&\s]+)&retailer=([^&\s]+)&site=test$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /?product=%1&retailer=%2 [R=301,L]

# second condition
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^retailer=([^&\s]+)&site=test$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /retailer/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^retailer/(.*)\+(.*)$ /retailer/$1-$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks for your response, I cant seem to get this to work. does this need to replace the rewrite in the second condition or does this need to be added as well?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention that the new rule should just be added to your current rules (see updated answer)

Comment: Thanks for the update but this still doesn't work :( i still just get redirected to retailer/test+test. It the last rule in my htaccess as well

Comment: Do you have other rules or something else in your htaccess ?

Comment: Sorry for the late response on this. the issue was my .htaccess being cached! took a while to figure out but your rule works. Thanks!